# Can Xcode project run on lower iOS versions?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have created an iOS application, such that the **Deployment Target is set to 10.3**. I have a iPhone 5s which has iOS version of **10.3.1**. I am able to run this developed application in my iPhone. Everything is working fine!!!

Then I thought to run the same application in my friend's iPhone. While running this application, Xcode was not able to run and gave me a warning that "**Update your iPhone to 10.3 to run this application.**". I opened the settings and found that the phone is currently running on iOS **10.1**.

I changed the Deployment target to **10.1**, and was able to run the application in my friend's iPhone. Right now I am confused, so I need help from you guys. Questions that are arising in my mind are:

1. Is this wrong that the application was not running, when the target was set to **10.3**?
2. After deploying this application in App Store, will all the users having iOS versions less than **10.3** be able run this application?

Every help will be appreciated. Thank you folks!

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html: *"The deployment target setting specifies the lowest operating system version that your app can run on."*

Comment: @MartinR OHkaaayy!! so this is the reason. Thanks man, I have searched for this but was not getting a proper result. Thanks man!! Saved my day. :)

Comment: It was the first Google hit for "xcode deployment target" :)

Comment: @MartinR Damn it!! I should have read the whole article. Somebody bang my head against the wall!!!!